# MVC 4 - 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

Yes I've searched the rest of s.o. for a solution, none of those solutions worked for me. Here's the issue:

1) Visual Studio 2012 -> New Web Site...

2) create a normal MVC 4 site (Razor v2) and .NET 4.5

3) add the following code to Default.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

}
```

4) launch and get this error:

```
CS1061: 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm' and no extension method 'BeginForm' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What gives?

EDIT, uploaded my website here as a zip, only 276K:
http://budzap.com/mvc.zip

Comment: It would help if you listed what's been tried: using statement exists, cleaned solution, removed .user project file, NUGET restore, etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692011/system-web-mvc-htmlhelper-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-actionlink

Comment: have you tried updating the web.config as seen here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041633/razor-views-not-seeing-system-web-mvc-htmlhelper

Comment: I tried about 20 various solutions across s.o., so didn't want to list them all but really nothing has helped. Tried goldeneye's fix but no effect. Added a link to a zip of my website, maybe someone can try running it real quick and get the same error.

Comment: Could u create solution and upload to the site.

Comment: Did already, it's at the bottom of the question, here too:
http://budzap.com/mvc.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message says the version of your System.Web.Mvc does not support `BeginForm`.It may have many causes.To find out the cause your problem,you can try one of this:

- It is usaually caused by deleting the second web.confing which resides in the view folder.see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041633/razor-views-not-seeing-system-web-mvc-htmlhelper)
- See the version of your `System.Web.Mvc` in References of your project.it might be an old version that doesnot support `BeginForm`.
- add `System.Web.Mvc.html` before `BeginForm` to see if there is such a method.

Comment: This is too speculative to be an answer. It should be a comment at most.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Razor version number in Views > Web.config match each other.

```
<section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0 [etc]
```

and

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0 [etc]
```

Comment: heh about 4 years too late, we don't even use BeginForm anymore but thx

Comment: Thanks buddy Hugh Seagraves

Comment: @Huge you are right - this is the case for me - System.Web.WebPages.Razor is 3.0.0.0 while System.Web.MvcSystem.Web.Mvc is 4.0.0.0 but how do I fix it? the PM says both are latest and just change manually gives of course an error. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Move your _layoutPage into the Views folder