# How can I encrypt the id querystring parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cryptography

I need to send "@id" parameter with encrypted (on browser search bar) then decrypted the id to get id's values from Edit view.How can I use AES cryptography.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    return view(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't encrypt and decrypt a parameter in a query string param in a URL. If you want to pass parameters between a client browser and host system, the parameter has to be buried in the content of the messaging between the host and client while the entire messaging is encrypted via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this steps :

**Step 1:** 
Create a new class in your project and copy paste the code from [This Link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/I24PV4).

**Step 2:** 
 Build the project now

**step 3:**

**Put the `MyExtension` namespace  on top of your page (view)**

```
@Html.EncodedActionLink(item.Name, "YourActionName", "YourControllerName", new { id = item.ID }, null)
```

**Step 4:**

```
[EncryptedActionParameter]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    return view(model);
}
```

**Edited :** 
After I did above steps I found a problem in decryption and I changed it.So you need to change `byte[] IV = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20 };` to `byte[] IV = { 55, 34, 87, 64, 87, 195, 54, 21 };` in `Decrypt` and `Encrypt` methods in `MyExtensions` class.

Comment: I add theese class,and 
[EncryptedActionParameter]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    return view(model);
} but it says "Html helper does not contains EncodedActionLink extension method"

Comment: Add this `using System.Web.Mvc.Html;`

Comment: Where,I added it but VStudio says its not on use.
And I'm using Devexpress,it happens in gridviewpartial

Comment: top of your extension class

Comment: see this link one of answer can solved your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/12692202/4118900 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/12692197/4118900 or https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/532

Comment: Now url is :"/Edit?q=+kBlw5MHdHA=  "  but I'm using like Edit/2, and its not decrypted on post page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195632/discussion-between-kerem-yilmaz-and-amin-saadati).

Comment: @KeremYılmaz I made a sample of it and it works fine and there is not any problem to encrypt your data